# A $3 \times 3$ matrix with unit row and unit column but all unique elements must be orthogonal matrix.

Tags: matrices, orthogonal-matrices

I am using basic matrix theory to prove that if a $3 \times 3$ matrix has unit rows and unit columns but all entries are unique then matrix must be orthogonal.
But I have trouble proving this. All I have is $9$ equations with $9$ unknowns.
Is there any other way to prove this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prove it because it is false. Repeatedly generate a random, entrywise positive [doubly stochastic matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_stochastic_matrix) $S$ until it has distinct elements. Then take its entrywise square root $R$. E.g.
$$
S=\frac{1}{30}\pmatrix{9&17&4\\ 10&6&14\\ 11&7&12}
\implies R=\frac{1}{\sqrt{30}}\pmatrix{3&\sqrt{17}&2\\ \sqrt{10}&\sqrt{6}&\sqrt{14}\\ \sqrt{11}&\sqrt{7}&\sqrt{12}}.
$$
By construction, all rows and columns of $R$ are unit vectors and all elements of $R$ are distinct, but $R$ cannot possibly be orthogonal because it is entrywise positive.

(In the above, if one allows taking *negative* square roots of some elements of $S$, then *sometimes* the resulting matrix $R$ is orthogonal. The matrix $S$ in this case is said to be [*orthostochastic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthostochastic_matrix).)

Alternatively, generate a random orthogonal matrix $U$ repeatedly until its elements have distinct *absolute values* and it has not any zero element on the first row or the first column. Then flip the sign of the first element of $U$ to obtain a new matrix $V$. E.g.
$$
U=\pmatrix{\frac{1}{\sqrt{35}}&\frac{7}{\sqrt{234}}&\frac{79}{\sqrt{8190}}\\ \frac{3}{\sqrt{35}}&\frac{11}{\sqrt{234}}&-\frac{43}{\sqrt{8190}}\\ \frac{5}{\sqrt{35}}&-\frac{8}{\sqrt{234}}&\frac{10}{\sqrt{8190}}}
\implies
V=\pmatrix{\color{red}{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{35}}}&\frac{7}{\sqrt{234}}&\frac{79}{\sqrt{8190}}\\ \frac{3}{\sqrt{35}}&\frac{11}{\sqrt{234}}&-\frac{43}{\sqrt{8190}}\\ \frac{5}{\sqrt{35}}&-\frac{8}{\sqrt{234}}&\frac{10}{\sqrt{8190}}}.
$$
The rows and columns of $V$ will then be unit vectors and all elements of $V$ are distinct, but $V$ by construction cannot be orthogonal.